# Determine a mod. 37 so that...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ be the greatest natural number that $4^{2016}+4^a+4^{37}$ is square of a natural number. Determine $a$ mod. $37$

Comment: Any thoughts? $\ $

Comment: I only found $a=937$. Then $a$ mod $37=28$. but I don't know if $a=937$ is the greatest number satisfying task...

Comment: How do you know 937 is a solution? Direct computation?

Comment: And in any case $a=1027$ is also a solution: $$\bigl(2^{37}(2^{1979}+1)\bigr)^2=4^{37}(4^{1979}+2^{1980}+1)=4^{2016}+4^{1027}+4^{37}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're looking for the largest such $a$, start with $a>37$.
Then $4^{37} + 4^{2016} +4^a = 4^{37} (1+4^{1979} + 4^{a-37})$ and that is a perfect square if and only if $N = 1+4^{1979} + 4^{a-37}$ is a perfect square.

Re-write $N$ as $$N = 1 + 4 \cdot 4^{1978} + 4\cdot 4^{2\cdot 1978} + (4^{a-37} - 4^{3957}) = (1+2\cdot 4^{1978})^2 + (4^{a-37} - 4^{3957}).$$

If the last parentheses is zero (which happens when $a=3994$), then $N$ is a perfect square.

Suppose that $a >3994$. Then
$$(2^{a-37}+1)^2 = 4^{a-37} + 2^{a-36} + 1 > 4^{a-37} + 2^{2\cdot 1979} +1 = N > (2^{a-37})^2, $$
hence $N$ is not a perfect square.

Therefore $a=3994$ and
$$a= 3994 = 3\cdot (999+1) + (999-5) \equiv -2 \pmod{37} \equiv 35\pmod{37},$$
because $999 = 37 \cdot 27$ is a multiple of 37.